# Exception thrown when binding ItemsControl to a UserControls collection

Tags: .net, silverlight, exception, user-controls, itemscontrol

In my application a templated form needs to show a list of usercontrols in a stackpanel. I figured I could use ItemsControl on the form and bind it to a collection that exposes the "child usercontrols". This approach works fine the first time when the templated form loads but if I make any changes to the Observable collection of child usercontrols, I get an exception "Value does not fall within the expected range".

I have looked thru many posts but none of the solutions seem to have worked. I am pasting a sample code  that shows the issue I am talking about. The sample code has

1. Mainpage with ItemsCOntrol in it. The Itemscontrol is bound to an
   Observablecollection of type AnyControl.
2. Class AnyControl has a public property AttachedControl. The
   AttachedControl is type object.

When the Mainpage loads, I create 2 instances of AnyControl and set the AttachedControl property to instances of Textboxes.

Mainpage has 3 buttons

1. Show All. which sets the datacontext of the mainpage and the two
   textboxes show up on the form.
2. Remove Second Control. clicking this
   button removes second entry from the ObservableCollection and the
   second textbox disappears.
3. Restore Second Control. clicking this
   button adds the second entry back into the Observable Collection.
   Logically the second textbox should show up on the form but instead
   I get the exception.

The code starts here.....
MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public AnyControl control1;
    public AnyControl control2;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        control1 = new AnyControl(new TextBox() { Text = "First Textbox" });
        control2 = new AnyControl(new TextBox() { Text = "Second Textbox" });

        _allVMs = new ObservableCollection<AnyControl>();
        _allVMs.Add(control1);
        _allVMs.Add(control2);
    }       

    private ObservableCollection<AnyControl> _allVMs;
    public ObservableCollection<AnyControl> ActiveViews
    {
        get { return _allVMs;}
        set
        {
            _allVMs = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ActiveViews");
        }
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = this; // RecordTemplate;
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ActiveViews.RemoveAt(1);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ActiveViews");
    }

    private void Button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ActiveViews.Add(control2);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ActiveViews");
    }            

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

AnyControl.cs

```
public class AnyControl
{
    public object AttachedControl { get; set; }
    public AnyControl(object control)
    {
        AttachedControl = control;
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:layoutToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit"
xmlns:layoutPrimitivesToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication2"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>           
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveViews}" x:Name="ItemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="a7777">
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="222"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding AttachedControl}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
    <Button Content="Show All" Height="22" Click="Button1_Click" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
        <Button Content="Remove second control" Height="22" Click="Button2_Click" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
        <Button Content="Restore second control" Height="22" Click="Button3_Click" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Any Help is much appreciated.
Thanks
A

Comment: Provide please an exception details

Comment: It throws "Value does not fall within the expected range." exception.

Comment: Its strange thing you are doing, trying to treat instances of UIElements like they are data like you are doing whilst theoretically possible is likely to cause you pain.  Why are you doing this?  It would seem to me that a better approach would be to bind actual data to the `Content` and a `DataTemplate` to `ContentTemplate`.

Comment: Hello AnthonyWJones, I am using ViewModelFirst approach of MVVM pattern where ViewModel decides which view to display. This is not a very common approach but is very useful when your views are ChildWindows.

Comment: "Value does not fall within the expected range" often indicates that your code results in a UIElement being placed within the visual tree more than once, hence it has mutlitple parents, which is not valid. I would suggest following the advice of  @AnthonyWJones

Comment: Hello ColinE, I did check if the control has multiple parents but that's not the case either. I have tried removing all controls from the Itemsource before updating the bound collection and also applied an iValueConverter in which I set the control's parent property to null before it gets added to the itemscontrol but nothing has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a custom control to solve this issue. Since all I wanted was to show usercontrols within a "parent" form, I ended up creating a custom panel control. Added a dependency property called ItemsSource to it. The handler for this property adds the custom controls in its collection to the panel's CHildren collection.

@ColinE, I did make sure that before adding a child control to the panel I check if it is child of another panel. If it is I obtain a reference to its parent panel control and remove the control from that parent panel's children collection.

It seems to work just fine.

Thanks for the comments.
A